# Is an action necessary when Sys.getenv and .libPaths return different folders for library location?

Tags: r

Is an action necessary when Sys.getenv and .libPaths return different folders for library location?

```
Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER") # value of the environment variable R_LIBS_USER
[1] "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents/R/win-library/3.1"  
.libPaths() # the library trees within which packages are looked for
[1] "C:/Revolution/R-Enterprise-7.3/R-3.1.1/library"
```

Looking at the help files of the functions, I added the above comments.

In such a case where there is a difference for the library location, is there a side effect in case no action is done?

Is there anything that I have to do (like setting library location above to be same) as a must?

Comment: Two things are interesting as well: (1) The return of Sys.getenv includes both "\\" and "/" in folder location! (2) There is no folder "C:\Users\User\Documents\R" in my notebook, but there is "C:\Users\User\Documents\Revolution", the latter being my R's working directory (I did nothing to set folder location previously till now). Hence,  Sys.getenv returns a value (for a folder) that even does not exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* the answer is "no". I discovered that my values are different and it has been causing me no difficulties. I prefer to keep all my packages in one library and never install to the default value from Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER") which is in my Users/ volume. My current `.libPaths()` are (is) :

```
"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library"
```

The GUI I use gives me the option of using the R_LIBS_USER location but I do not choose to do so because it has lead to duplication and confusion on my part in the past. You can make other choices, possibly in the 'preferences" for your GUI or optionally in your `.Rprofile` settings (which a hidden "dotfile" on both Windows and Macs so you need to know how to make them visible on your OS if using the system browser/explorer.)